# What happens with data stream when it is proxified by Nginx?

Tags: nginx, web-server, proxy

I have this nginx config:

```
stream {
    upstream ssh {
        server 192.168.29.139:22;
    }

    upstream web {
        server 192.168.29.139:444;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
        "" ssh;
        default web;
        "TLSv1.2" web;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

It is proxy for nginx Docker container and local OpenSSH Server. I have only one opened port on this machine - 443. It is works perfectly fine: i can use ssh on 443 and work with website by https in browser.

But i wonder what happens with data? For example, when i connect through SSH, i still hold connection and work through nginx proxy? Is it bad for connection? Will it slow down connection speed to my website since there is actually two Nginx servers in line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a connection to that Nginx, if your client does not initiate some TLS handshake, then it is assumed to be a new SSH session, and forwarded to your ssh upstream, otherwise it is sent to your web server.

Is it "bad" for connection: not really. Depends what you consider to be bad.

It acts as a TCP relay. The main difference with direct access would be that, from your SSH container point of view, connections would all establish from your reverse proxy IP.

Thus, if you were to use something like `fail2ban` or any kind of IP filtering, then this would not work, you might have to consider setting up some `IDS/IPS` in front or alongside your Nginx container.

Then again, this is probably not your case. Besides this, there shouldn't be much difference with direct accesses.